# Pergunta com votos mas respostas sem

Tags: suporte

Recentemente fiz [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295234) no site, até agora, ela teve 12 votos o que eu considero no mínimo pertinente, porém todas as respostas dela, até o momento não possuem votos, exceto uma que possui somente 1 voto a favor. A diferença é bem chamativa, principalmente porque, geralmente (pelo menos que eu vi nesses últimos meses de SOpt), é ao contrário, respostas tem mais votos que as perguntas

Isso significa o que?

Imagino que se as respostas estivessem incorretas ou com algum problema grave elas estariam negativas, porém não houve votos a favor nem contras, nem sinalizações de fechamento

Comment: Provavelmente o pessoal julgou as respostas corretas, mas ainda assim insuficientes. Eu mesmo acho que dado o conteúdo da pergunta, uma resposta que considero boa seria um tanto quanto extensa, abordando todos os conceitos por trás da PWA (e não necessariamente das ferramentas).

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss também achei as respostas focadas de mais em frameworks e não no que eles usam por baixo dos panos, nisso que estou interessado, talvez eu deveria ter especificado mais na pergunta

Answer (score -2):

Significa que 13 pessoas acharam sua pergunta pertinente, mas, não olharam as respostas porque não era do interesse deles, ou deram os votos na sua pergunta quando ainda não tinha nenhuma resposta e não olharam a pergunta depois para julgar as respostas

Comment: A resposta está correta. Fico imaginando por que cinco pessoas votaram contra.

Comment: Talvez porque cinco pessoas não gostaram da minha resposta porque acharam que ela tinha um tom irônico, mas garanto que não foi proposital